# How can I have hundreds of subscribers in paho-mqtt?

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I would like to simulate a system with 100 subscribers and 100 publishers, I am using mosquitto as a broker and the clients are two python scripts. The side of the publishers I have managed to configure it with 100 publishers, using python threads, but I have doubts to implement the same in the subscribers part.

I mean to create a list with all clients and then create a thread for each client, that is what I implemented in the publishers, but in the subscribers to create a target is difficult because there are several functions that must be executed.

```
for client_id, client in all_clients:
     t = threading.Thread (target = sending, args = (client, client_id))
     t.start ()
     all_threads.append (t)
 
# at the end wait for end of threads
for t in all_threads:
     t.join ()
```

Can someone suggest to me how I could implement it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think subscribers would be any different from publishers? MQTT clients can do both at the same time

Comment: Also how does this question differ from your last one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65984568/how-to-run-multiple-subcribers-at-the-same-time-paho-mqtt

Comment: Yes, exactly both can do the same, but in my case I would like my subscribers not to be the same publishers, but only recipients of messages, I don't know if I explain myself.